# MySQL - count and group by - display all results in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I think this should be simple, but I can't figure it out or find a solution here.

I have a table ITEM_PROPERTIES

```
item_ID int
property_name char(20)
property_value char(20)
```

Sample data

```
5   Colour  Black
5   Size    M   
6   Colour  Blue
6   Size    L   
7   Colour  Purple
7   Size    M   
8   Colour  Blue
8   Size    S   
9   Colour  Wine
9   Size    M
```

If I do:

```
SELECT property_value, count(property_value) 
FROM ITEM_PROPERTIES where property_name='Colour'
group by property_value
```

I get :

```
Black   1
Blue    2
Purple  1
Wine    1
```

How can I get this on one row like:

```
Black 1, Blue 2, Purple 1, Wine 1
```

I tried :

```
SELECT group_concat(property_value, count(property_value)) 
FROM ITEM_PROPERTIES where property_name='Colour'
group by property_value

SELECT group_concat(concat(property_value, count(property_value))) 
FROM ITEM_PROPERTIES where property_name='Colour'
group by property_value
```

But both give an error  Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select group_concat(concat(property_value, '  ', cnt))
from (
    SELECT property_value, count(property_value) as cnt
     FROM ITEM_PROPERTIES
     WHERE property_name = 'Colour'
     GROUP BY property_value
) c
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT group_concat(property_value, ' ', cnt separator ', ')
FROM (SELECT property_value, count(property_value) as cnt
      FROM ITEM_PROPERTIES
      WHERE property_name = 'Colour'
      GROUP BY property_value
     ) ip;
```

Comment: Thank you both @Pavel Zimogorov and Gordan - I accepted the the first response as both are the same

Comment: @KevInSol . . . The OP can accept whichever answer s/he likes.  But, you can move your mouse over the time frame ("answered . . . ago").  You'll see that this answer was 2 minutes 55 seconds earlier than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please check the following function it will be useful for any query for any later uses :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "JOIN"
(
    p_cursor  sys_refcursor
   ,p_del     VARCHAR2:=','
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    l_value   VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_result  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH p_cursor INTO l_value;
        EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        IF  l_result IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            l_result:=l_result || p_del;
        END IF;
        l_result:=l_result || l_value;
    END LOOP;

    close p_cursor;
    RETURN l_result;
END JOIN;
```

To call this function use the following sample :

```
SELECT Join(CURSOR(select column from tableName)) FROM DUAL;
```

Cheers